# Count unique values across multiple columns

Tags: excel-2010

I have data in this format

```
A B C D
1 1 1 1
1 1 1 2
1 1 1 3
1 1 1 4
...
4 4 4 4
```

I want to count number of unique values in each row and print it
output:

```
A B C D  unique-count
1 1 1 1  4
1 1 1 2  3
1 1 1 3  3
1 1 1 4  3
...
4 4 4 4  4
```